# How to fix Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I had Ubuntu installed, after installing Windows 7 and trying to fix Windows bootloader (using EasyBCD), my Ubuntu partition is damaged.This is screenshot of GParted:
[image]

`/dev/sda3 extended` is recent Ubuntu partition. All context menu options are disabled but information and Manage flags. Information status is `Busy`. **I have some important files on Ubuntu**. How can i fix it?

The installer detect `/dev/sda3` as free space and get following error on trying to use it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On gParted :

Left-clic on `/dev/sda5` (linux-swap), and select "swapoff"

We can see here that the swap is still mounted (the key next to `/dev/sda5`), causing the extended partition to stay bussy.Using the swapoff option will unmount it.

That for the "busy problem".

For the lost partition problem:

Install gpart :

```
sudo apt-get install gpart
```

Open the "Devices" menu of GParted, and select "try to recover data" (something like that, my computer use French as language, i'm not sure of the english equivalent)

**Edit 1 :**

Try testdisk

installation :

```
sudo apt-get install TestDisk
```

Use : Open a new Terminal ( `ctrl+alt+T` )

```
sudo testdisk
```

And follow this step-by-step tutorial : [TestDisk step-by-step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: I did what you told. It took a long time but no filesystem found :(

Comment: Also Partition table of /dev/sda is msdos. Is it correct?

Comment: I won't pose any problem imho

Comment: New edit, with a new software : TestDisk